# Labeling via majority vote of connected clusters in python3

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, classification

I have a tensor with three dimensions and three classes (0: background, 1: first class, 2: second class). I would like to find connected clusters and assign outlier's labels by performing a majority vote. A 2D example:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2],
                 [1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],])
```

should be changed to

```
data = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2],
                 [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],])
```

It is enough to see connected regions as one cluster an count the appearence of the labels. I am not looking for any machine learning method.

Comment: I would be very surprised to discover there is something pre-built for that. You will need to built a function that for each data-point finds the more popular neighbours type (1's or 2's), and change its value if needed. You will have to determind how you define "neighbour" (like 4 squares or 8), and how many neighbours you need to conclude to change the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.ndimage.measurements.label` to find the connected components and then use `np.bincount` for the counting

```
from scipy.ndimage import measurements

lbl,ncl = measurements.label(data)

lut = np.bincount((data+2*lbl).ravel(),None,2*ncl+3)[1:].reshape(-1,2).argmax(1)+1
lut[0] = 0

lut[lbl]
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2],
#        [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
#        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! How can I add a threshold there? For example: If 30% or more of a cluster is of label = 2, then set all labels of that cluster to 2. If less than 30% are of label = 2, then set cluster to label = 1.

Comment: @Anno Could you try `lut = (np.bincount((data+2*lbl).ravel(),None,2*ncl+3)[1:].reshape(-1,2) * (3,7)).argmax(1)+1`?

Comment: Works! Thank you!